# Difference between /thanks and /thanks/ (http status 301)

Tags: php, apache

I have a website and one of the sub folders is /thanks.

So the complete URI for the (one) page would be

```
/thanks/index.php
```

Now when i type

`/thanks/` i get a 200 return status and it picks up the (default) page `index.php`

however, when I type 
`/thanks` I get a 301 redirect to `/thanks/`

```
<address>Apache/2.2.8 (Linux/SUSE) Server at www.mydomain.net Port 80</address>
```

While the behaviour is correct, I would like the `/thanks` to also serve the `/thanks/` folder directly, without the 301.

Is that possible?

By the way, it looks like apache is generating the 301 'automatically', I wonder: what page or source is actually called when you call `/thanks` in stead of `/thanks/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is by design, cause url "/thanks" should actually refer to the file. Only for your convenience a web-server checks whether such file exists, if not then whether such directory exists, and if it is, it redirects the request to the correct destination "/thanks/".

It is actually a best practice to enforce/use trailing slash wherever possible, it is a canonical form, it reduces load on the web server (parsing one HTTP request instead of two - original and redirect), and improves your search engine optimization.

As for how to fix this, the question whether it needs fixing is still standing. If you fix this through say URL rewrite, your users will keep using the incorrect/bad-for-your-SEO URL. If you fix all the links at your site to use correct form and employ the default fix scheme - redirect - then the redirect would once redirect your users to the correct URL, and users will be using the correct version by default foreverafter (at least, in this session).

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem you face is that you could end up supplying multiple addresses for the same page...

```
/thanks
/thanks/
/thanks/index.php
```

When people link back to your website and search engines crawl your pages, the "kudos" that belongs to

```
/thanks/
```

Will be divided between the three addresses and your page could end up much further down in the search results than would otherwise be the case.

By enforcing the trailing slash, you remove one possibility for problems.

Therefore, I wholeheartedly recommend sticking with the convention of "enforcing" the trailing the slash.

Answer (score 1):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Since Apache 2, you could turn it off if you don't like the trailing slash redirection. However, please read everything carefully, make sure you do know what you are doing (which is NOT a recommend thing to do)

Comment: Especially SEO reasons mentioned by Kaerber and Sohnee, and security implication documented.